# Flash Messages syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting `end'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i use haml and i want to use flash messsages but i have a syntax error, when create the partial _messages.html.haml and rendering in the devise.html.haml i have this error:

```
ActionView::SyntaxErrorInTemplate in Devise::SessionsController#new

Encountered a syntax error while rendering template: check - flash.each do |name, msg| - if msg.is_a?(String) %br %div{:class => "alert alert-#{name.to_s == 'notice' ? 'success' : 'danger'}"} %button.close{"aria-hidden" => "true", "data-dismiss" => "alert", :type => "button"} &times; = content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}"

Extracted source (around line #8):
6 = content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}"

> Rails.root: /organizator Application
> Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
> app/views/layouts/_messages.html.haml:8: syntax error, unexpected
> end-of-input, expecting `end' app/views/layouts/_messages.html.haml:8:
> syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting `end'

> app/views/layouts/_messages.html.haml:8: syntax error, unexpected
> end-of-input, expecting `end' app/views/layouts/_messages.html.haml:8:
> syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting `end'

> app/views/layouts/_messages.html.haml:8: syntax error, unexpected
> end-of-input, expecting `end' app/views/layouts/_messages.html.haml:8:
> syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting `end'

> app/views/layouts/devise.html.haml:13

Exception Causes
SyntaxError: /organizator/app/views/layouts/_messages.html.haml:8: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting `end'
```

in the terminal i have this:

```
> ActionView::SyntaxErrorInTemplate (Encountered a syntax error while
> rendering template: check - flash.each do |name, msg|
>   - if msg.is_a?(String)  %br     %div{:class => "alert alert-#{name.to_s == 'notice' ? 'success' : 'danger'}"}       %button.close{"aria-hidden" => "true", "data-dismiss" => "alert", :type => "button"} &times;        =
> content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" ): 1:    - flash.each do
> |name, msg| 2:        - if msg.is_a?(String) 3:       %br 4:   
>   %div{:class => "alert alert-#{name.to_s == 'notice' ? 'success' :
> 'danger'}"} 5:            %button.close{"aria-hidden" => "true",
> "data-dismiss" => "alert", :type => "button"} &times; 6:          =
> content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}"
> 
> app/views/layouts/_messages.html.haml:8: syntax error, unexpected
> end-of-input, expecting `end' app/views/layouts/_messages.html.haml:8:
> syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting `end'
> app/views/layouts/_messages.html.haml:8: syntax error, unexpected
> end-of-input, expecting `end' app/views/layouts/_messages.html.haml:8:
> syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting `end'
> app/views/layouts/_messages.html.haml:8: syntax error, unexpected
> end-of-input, expecting `end' app/views/layouts/_messages.html.haml:8:
> syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting `end'
> app/views/layouts/devise.html.haml:13
```

My devise template devise.html.haml
app/views/layouts/devise.html.haml

```
!!!
%html
    %head
        %meta{:content => "text/html; charset=UTF-8", "http-equiv" => "Content-Type"}/
        %title Tasker
        = csrf_meta_tags
        = csp_meta_tag
        = javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
        = stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
    %body
        .container
            .main-flash-messages
                = render 'layouts/messages'
        .fullscreen
            .container
                = yield
```

My partial _messages.html.haml
app/views/layouts/_messages.html.haml

```
- flash.each do |name, msg|
    - if msg.is_a?(String)
    %br
    %div{:class => "alert alert-#{name.to_s == 'notice' ? 'success' : 'danger'}"}
        %button.close{"aria-hidden" => "true", "data-dismiss" => "alert", :type => "button"} &times;
        = content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}"
```

I tryed to solve this reading the documentation of haml but i don't know what is wrong. Regards.

Comment: Please make sure to format error messages and code as code, not as block quotes. Newlines and leading whitespace is generally important and needs to be preserved. The error messages in your question are mostly unreadable right now. See [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362/421705) for some guidance here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with HAML but I expect that the content that depends on the `if` condition needs to be indented and would therefore try:

```
- flash.each do |name, msg|
  - if msg.is_a?(String)
    %br
    %div{:class => "alert alert-#{name.to_s == 'notice' ? 'success' : 'danger'}"}
      %button.close{"aria-hidden" => "true", "data-dismiss" => "alert", :type => "button"} &times;
      = content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}"
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, that is the problem, the identation of the if.